# How can we prove that the Hamiltonian for any quantum system is Hermitian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, unitarity

By applying partial time derivative to
$$\psi_t \rightarrow U \psi_{t_0}$$
we end up with an expression for the Hamiltonian
$$H = i\hbar\frac{\partial U_{t}}{\partial t}U^{\dagger}_{t}$$
where $U$ is the unitary time evolution operator. 
How can we show that $(\partial U_{t} / \partial t) U^\dagger_t$ is anti-Hermitian? If $(\partial U_t / \partial t)U^\dagger_t$ is anti-Hermtian surely we can multiply $i$ to  $(\partial U_t / \partial t)U^\dagger_t$ which would make $i(\partial U_t/\partial t)U^\dagger_t$ Hermitian. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $U_t$ is unitary, we have:

$$U_t U_t^\dagger = \mathbb I$$

Taking a derivative from both sides:

$$\frac{\partial U_t}{\partial t} U_t^\dagger +U_t (\frac{\partial U_t}{\partial t})^\dagger =0$$

so:

$$\frac{\partial U_t}{\partial t} U_t^\dagger =-U_t (\frac{\partial U_t}{\partial t})^\dagger$$

or:

$$\frac{\partial U_t}{\partial t} U_t^\dagger = -\Big(\frac{\partial U_t}{\partial t} U_t^\dagger \Big)^\dagger$$

Meaning that $\frac{\partial U_t}{\partial t} U_t^\dagger$ is anti-Hermitian.

**EDIT:**

The OP brings up an interesting question in the comments: Can any anti-Hermitian operator-valued function $A(t)$ be written in the form $\dot{U}(t) U^\dagger(t)$ for some unitary operator $U(t)$?

The answer is yes, as long as $A(t)$ is differentiable. To see this, let's define the operator $U(t)$ through the following initial value problem:

$$\dot{U}(t) = A(t) U(t) \qquad \text{with} \quad U(0) = \mathbb I \qquad (*)$$

First of all, taking the Hermitian conjugate of $(*)$ we get:

$$\dot{U}^\dagger(t) = -U^\dagger(t)A(t)  \qquad \text{with} \quad U^\dagger(0) = \mathbb I \qquad (**)$$

Using $(*),(**)$ we can show that $U(t)$ is indeed unitary. Let's calculate the derivative of $U^\dagger(t) U(t)$:

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t} \Big(U^\dagger(t) U(t) \Big) =  \dot{U}^\dagger(t)  U(t) +U^\dagger(t) \dot{U}(t) = -U^\dagger (t) A(t) U(t)+U^\dagger(t) A(t) U(t) = 0$$

So $U^\dagger(t) U(t)$ is constant in time meaning that:

$$U^\dagger(t) U(t)= U^\dagger(0) U(0) = \mathbb I$$

Therefore, $U(t)$ is indeed unitary. Now from $(*)$ we can easily write:

$$A(t) = \dot{U}(t) U^\dagger(t)$$

meaning that we've proved our claim.

**Second EDIT:**

Emilio Pisanty points out in the comments that our defining initial value problem for $U$ may not have a solution in the general case of an infinite dimensional Hilbert space. The above argument obviously breaks down for those settings.

Comment: Beat me to it; it’s a very simple argument :)

Comment: Wait still kinda confused as to why ∂/∂ ^† is antihermtian.. i don't understand the argument... could u kindly elaborate a little :) I know hermitian operator is a conjugate transpose... so can u kindly lead from there. I new to this kinda stuff....

Comment: Basically, we know that for a unitary operator, the inverse is the same as the Hermitian conjugate (that's the first equation). Then, by taking a time derivative of both sides, we showed that $\partial U_t / \partial t \times U_t^\dagger$ is the same as minus its Hermitian conjugate, which means that it's anti-Hermitian (by definition). Is there a specific step which needs clarification?

Comment: @SahandTabatabaei no the steps are pretty clear, thx a lot! I was just confused with the definition of anti-Hermtian. What I am saying is that how did u come up with the idea that ∂/∂×^† is anti Hermtian. I get what u said here "by taking a time derivative of both sides, we showed that ∂/∂×^† is the same as minus its Hermitian conjugate, which means that it's anti-Hermitian (by definition)" but by definition what definition are u refering to. Are u saying Anti-Hermitian by defined as a time derivative??

Comment: I meant the definition of an anti-Hermitian operator. An operator $A$ is called anti-Hermitian when it's equal to to minus its own adjoint, so $A = - A^\dagger$. Now take $A = \partial U_t / \partial t \times U_t^\dagger$ in this definition, that's the same as the final equation in my answer.

Comment: So then it's true... anti-hermitian can written in a differential of the unitary operator. Hence u arrive to the argument for the anti hermitian by taking the derivative for the definition of unitary operator... YESSS?

Comment: No, any operator that can be written as $\partial U_t / \partial t \times U_t^\dagger$, with $U_t$ being a unitary operator for all $t$, is an anti-Hermitian operator. This *does not mean that any anti-Hermitian operator can be written in that form.* For example, $A := i \sigma_x$ is anti-Hermitian, but since it doesn't depend on any parameter $t$, it can't be written in that $\partial U_t / \partial t \times U_t^\dagger$ form.

Comment: Okay I get it... unitary operator that depend upon time can be written in such a form, where A as the anti-hermitian can be written as a diffferential. Am a getting this right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96981/discussion-between-epic-tube-hd-and-sahand-tabatabaei).

Comment: "let's define the operator $U(t)$ through the following initial value problem" - so long as the IVP has a solution, which need not be guaranteed; this is where all the complicated functional analysis lives.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty That's true, I guess I swept those technicalities under the rug. This would at least work for finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces. But the solution is not guarantied to exist in the general case.

Comment: I don't think sweeping technicalities under the rug is a problem, particularly if your audience wouldn't cope, but it's always best to mark those points explicitly in the text.

Comment: You are absolutely right :)